# How is logback's "prudent mode" implemented?

Tags: java, delphi, logging, log4j, logback

The [prudent mode](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#prudent) in logback serializes IO operations between all JVMs writing to the same file, potentially running on different hosts. In other logging frameworks, logging to a central TCP (or JMS) appender seems to be the only solution if output from many loggers should go to the same file.

As I am using a Delphi library which is based on log4j and also can not log to the same file from different instances of the same applications (on a terminal server), it would be interesting to know how this feature is implemented. - p.s. I'll check the logback source code and come back to answer my question if nobody is faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's implemented with a simple [FileLock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html). You can check in the source of [FileAppender](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/FileAppender.java#L179).