# Synchronize shared file writing inside a JVM and across JVMs

Tags: java, concurrency, nio, file-locking

I have 2 distinct tomcat7 servers, on each the same web service is deployed. Each web service request has to update a file on a shared flesystem (typically a NAS).
The file writing has to be synchronized to avoid conflict within the JVM of a tomcat server but also between JVM of the 2 servers.
I tried several methods :

=> A synchronized block for the file writing works only in the same JVM.

=> A FileLock works for each JVM but not within the JVM of a server (a file can be locked only once).

And how about using the Java7 nio file system ? can this help me ?
What is the best way to solve this problem ?

PS : sorry if my english is bad...

Comment: This is similar to Logback's "prudent mode", see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7138838/3080094

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two approaches:

1. Use `synchronized` (or a `Lock`) and also `FileLock`; i.e. first obtain a local lock on a unique object that denotes the canonicalized absolute pathname, and then acquire a `FileLock`.
2. Use a database; e.g. lock a row in a database table which has the canonicalized absolute pathname as a unique key.

---

> And how about using the Java7 nio file system ? can this help me ?

No.  The problem is that file locking is OS functionality, and the behaviour (not locking against other threads in the same process) is fundamental file locking semantics ... across a range of different operating systems.